# merging two git remote repositories locally

Tags: git-merge, pull-request

I want to make use of this feature -- https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/pull/160. Although this issue has been closed, it has not been merged with the master. Is it possible to clone the master on my local machine and merge pull request #160 on my local copy? If so, how can I do it?

Master branch is https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind that this pull request has been closed because:

> Thanks a lot for this pull request but this will be fixed by adding overloads with `Strings` which will fix also issue [#74](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/74)

So your merge might come in conflict with a future patch which will be merged to `master`.

That being said, a pull request [is a **patch**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8279647/6309), so you can view it as a diff (select `diff` button on the pull request page), copy those diffs in a patch file, and apply it to your local repo (as in "[How to apply `git diff` patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418277/how-to-apply-git-diff-patch)")

Comment: Thank you :). Once it is merged with the master, I would use that. I want to get started now, so thought of doing a local merge.

Answer (score 2):

I see you've accepted VonC's answer, but you can do it this way, too. It's a little bit faster.

From: http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/

> Every pull request has a .patch URL where you can grab a textual patch file to feed into the git-am command:

In your case you can go like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis.git
$ curl https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/pull/160.patch | git am
```

Comment: Thank you for the response :). This one does seem easier. But I cannot accept two responses as answers, so I am up voting it.