# What does "apply patch" do in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github

I always used "Share Project" to integrate Eclipse project with GitHub. However, I was always curious about "Apply Patch".

**What does "Apply Patch" do in Eclipse?**

I assume "Create Patch" is also related to "Apply Patch"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It does what `diff` and `patch` does in Unix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find this in the official [Eclipse Documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-68c.htm)

> Patches allow developers to share work without storing it in a repository. This is helpful when a developer wants to contribute to a project that is shared through a repository but does not have write access to the repository. In this situation, the developer can create a patch and either e-mail it to a developer who does have write access or attach it to a bug in the bug reporting system used by the project, depending on the process defined by the project. A developer that does have write access can then apply the patch to the project and commit the changes.

Also see [What is a patch in git version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279602/what-is-a-patch-in-git-version-control/8279621)